# How to concatenate a million files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) for Google Cloud Storage, there are a few limitations on using `gsutil compose` (see below).

Is there a more efficient way to combine a large number of files in the same bucket (~1 million)?

If I understand correctly, I would have to join groups of 32, then keep doing that and joining again?

> Note that there is a limit (currently 32) to the number of components that can be composed in a single operation.
>
> There is a limit (currently 1024) to the total number of components for a given composite object. This means you can append to each object at most 1023 times.
>
> There is a per-project rate limit (currently 200) to the number of components you can compose per second. This rate counts both the components being appended to a composite object as well as the components being copied when the composite object of which they are a part is copied.

Comment: I'm curious - what's your use case for composing a million objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, combining groups of 32 over and over again won't work, due to the "grand total" components limit of 1024.

Instead, what you'd have to do is this:

1. Let's name the set of 1 million original files A (~1,000,000 objects).
2. Call compose on each group of 32 objects in A, producing set B (~30,000 objects). Each object in B has a component count of 32.
3. Call compose on groups of each group of 32 objects in B, producing set C (~1000 objects). These new objects will have 32*32 components each, or 1024. That's exactly the limit. You cannot compose them directly any further.
4. Call "rewrite" on each element of C. This will reset the component count back to 1.
5. Call compose on each group of 32 elements in C, producing set D (~30 objects).
6. Call compose once to combine all of D.

Much of this work can be done in parallel, which would greatly speed things up.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that "rewriting" in the same location or storage class does not reset the component count. Unfortunately, a really hacky approach is needed for something that it's supposed to be a reasonably simple operation.

Answer (score 7):

GCS no longer enforces a component count limit. You can combine 1 million files as long as the newly created object is <= 5 TiB. You still have to join the files in groups of 32 by composing recursively, as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects).

A simple way to do this in serial is by appending to a single object by repeatedly overwriting it. For example:

1. Upload the files as objects {F<sub>i</sub>, F<sub>i+1</sub>, ... F<sub>total</sub>}
2. Compose objects {F<sub>1</sub>, F<sub>2</sub>, ... F<sub>31</sub>} to create composite object X
3. Recursively compose objects {X, F<sub>i+1</sub>, F<sub>i+2</sub>, ... F<sub>i+30</sub>} to overwrite X with a new object

Since the compose per-project rate limit has also been lifted, you can also do this in parallel by composing in batches to temporary objects, then deleting the temporary objects.

2. Compose objects {F<sub>i</sub>, F<sub>i+1</sub>, ... F<sub>i+31</sub>} to create composite object X<sup>(1)</sup><sub>i / 32</sub>
3. Recursively compose objects {X<sup>(m)</sup><sub>j</sub>, X<sup>(m)</sup><sub>j+1</sub>, ... X<sup>(m)</sup><sub>j+31</sub>} to create composite object X<sup>(m+1)</sup><sub>j / 32</sub>
4. Delete all temporary objects X<sup>(m)</sup><sub>j</sub>

The only caveat is that the `componentCount` metadata property saturates at 2,147,483,647, even if the object has > 2,147,483,647 components. If you don't depend on `componentCount` being accurate, then this should not be a problem, since `componentCount` does not affect whether compose succeeds or not.

Comment: The limits have not been lifted for us. `gsutil version: 4.41` (released on 2019-07-16) still shows the limit: `Note that there is a limit (currently 32) to the number of components that can be composed in a single operation.`

And the error is still raised: `CommandException: "compose" called with too many component objects. Limit is 32.`

I'm trying to compose a few gigabytes here.

Comment: @nfo that is not what Mike meant. One compose operation can only merge 32 objects, but after that you can continue merging previously-merged objects with others without limit

Comment: Another caveat to keep in mind: "While there is no limit to the number of components that a composite object can contain, the componentCount metadata property of an object saturates at 2,147,483,647. For example, say you have an object that contains 3,000,000,000 components. In this case, the componentCount for the object has a value of 2,147,483,647."

Comment: Thanks manesioz@. I updated my answer to explain the 32 limit and componentCount property.

Comment: Does compose maintains the order of objects provided in the command ?

Comment: Compose maintains the order.

Comment: Keep in mind that a single object can be updated at most once per second: https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects